# db_update drupal 7 problems

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Whenever I use this it updates everyone in the database to the same rank

```
if (isset($_POST['adduser'])) {
  db_update('members')
  ->fields(array(
 'rank' => $_POST['person_rank'],
 ))
 ->where('name' <> $_POST['person'])
 ->execute();
header('Location: http://www.krokgaming.org/members');
}
```

I've tried, `->where('name' =` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the conditionals correctly. The first argument should be just the field, not the comparison operator and the value you're comparing (which will actually resolve to a boolean).

Change:

`->where('name' <> $_POST['person'])`

to be:

`->condition('name', $_POST['person'], '<>')`

If you want to use the `where()` method, you must pass it an actual where clause (your snippet evaluates the comparison and passes a boolean), along with named arguments:

`->where('name <> :name', array(':name' => $_POST['person']))`

Additionally, you should really sanitize POST data prior to using it.

Oh, and for Drupal questions you should really check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There's no reason to use `check_plain()` there - it's for escaping _output_ (not input) so I'd recommend removing that. PDO will handle the necessary MySQL sanitisation

Comment: I prefer to play it safe and not expect other tools/scripts to sanitize the data (personal preference), but it's a fair enough observation, so I'll edit it out in this case.